# Best practices for creating a data log

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a program that will run a bunch of motors. These motors interface to a motor controller, that my program talks to as well. I can tell the motor controller to periodically give me data about its state, as well as the state and position of each motor. I plan to have a live view of this data, so the operator can easily see if something is wrong, and additionally create a log of this data, so someone can go back afterwards and see what went wrong, and possibly why.

Here comes the question: What should I consider when creating this log? I am fresh out of college and have never really encountered a situation such as this. Of course I know how to create a file, put data into it, and close the file, but is there more to a data log?

Things I have already considered are:

1. It'd be good to have time stamps to each data record.
2. it may be ideal to be verbose with the data, rather than keep it binary. Longer setup time, better end result.
3. I must be careful to close the file up, regardless of how the program is ended.
4. I am using C++/CLI, I wonder if MSFT has some framework to make this straight forward...
5. Minimize cpu/disk usage, by testing if its better to write an entry each time it is received, or if it's better to wait until you have a couple entries and write them all at once.

What else should I consider?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, what comes to mind is a comma-separated or tab-separated file. These will be human-readable in notepad, or you can bring it into Excel, and make graphs of the data. (Though I'm sure someone out there will consider CSV or tab-SV to be far away from 'best practice'. However, it's simple to implement, simple to read, and readable in hundreds of apps. That's a pretty darned good practice in my book.)

You can do something similar to this:

```
FileStream^ textFileStream = gcnew FileStream(logFileName, FileMode::Append, FileAccess::Write, FileShare::Read);
StreamWriter^ textFileWriter = gcnew StreamWriter(textFileStream, Encoding::Unicode);
textFileWriter->AutoFlush = true;
```

1. For a timestamp, just dump out `DateTime::Now->ToString()`.
2. See above for some objects you can use. Use String::Format and send the output to the StreamWriter, that'll give you a verbose, human-readable log.
3. If you're worried about what happens if your program crashes, don't worry about that too much. The StreamWriter as initialized above will write through to the FileStream as you use it, which will in turn write to the filesystem. This won't do a filesystem-level flush, only a filesystem-level write (the data will be in the OS's write-back cache, to be flushed to disk at some point in the next few seconds), so if the OS crashes, your log file will be incomplete, but a program crash will be handled file.
4. There are various logging frameworks available for .Net, which you can use from C++/CLI, but I'm not too familiar with them.
5. Even if you're logging the data each second, it's doubtful that you need to worry about batching up the data. Let's say you had hundreds of motors to write data for: that's what, 1 kilobyte per second? maybe 2? Just write the data out as needed. (If you want to minimize disk/CPU usage, consider just logging the data less frequently, once per 10 seconds or once per minute.)

Comment: Seems reasonable-- I am thinking it'd be best to have the logger running in its own thread, and trigger an event with the data I want logged contained in it. I will start implementation today, and come back with any other thoughts as I have them, thanks!